# Trouble iterating struct

Tags: c++, oop

I have a bitfield struct called DescriptorByte aligned to 1 byte and a struct for holding lots of DescriptorByte like this:

```
struct DescriptorByte
{
    unsigned char IsImmedCalc : 1;
    unsigned char IsPrefix : 1;
    unsigned char NoMemOp : 1;
    unsigned char Size : 5;
};

struct OpcodeList
{
    DescriptorByte ADD_EB_GB;
    DescriptorByte ADD_EV_GV;
    DescriptorByte ADD_GB_EB;
    DescriptorByte ADD_GV_EV;
    DescriptorByte ADD_8_OI =   { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE + IMMED_8 };
    DescriptorByte ADD_32_OI =  { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE + IMMED_32 };
    DescriptorByte PUSH_ES =    { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE };
    DescriptorByte POP_ES =     { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE };
    DescriptorByte OR_EB_GB;
        //ETC
};
```

What i want to do is based on a number (byte) iterating through the struct like this:

```
OpcodeList opcodelist;
BYTE count = 5;
DescriptorByte = opcodelist + count;
```

Since the bitfield struct is aligned to 1 byte i should get the 5th element of the OpcodeList table, but i dont know how to make this on C++ i only know how to make it in ASM :/

```
LEA EAX, OPCODELIST
MOV ECX, COUNT
MOV EAX, DWORD PTR [EAX+ECX];
AND EAX, 0FF;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access this "list" multiple ways: By name (like `ADD_EB_GB`), and by index. You can't do this with a struct.

I would suggest using a `std::vector<DescriptorByte>` (or `std::array`). This way you can access by index. And if you still need to access by name, make your names constant indices into this vector.

A bit like this:

```
typedef std::array<DescriptorByte, 9> OpcodeList;

enum OpcodeIndex
{
    ADD_EB_GB = 0,
    ADD_EV_GV,
    ADD_GB_EB,
    ADD_GV_EV,
    ADD_8_OI,
    ADD_32_OI,
    PUSH_ES,
    POP_ES,
    OR_EB_GB
}
```

...

```
// instantiate & initialize an opcode list.
OpcodeList opcodeList =
{
    { ... },// ADD_EB_GB,
    { ... },// ADD_EV_GV,
    { ... },// ADD_GB_EB,
    { ... },// ADD_GV_EV,
    { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE + IMMED_8 },// ADD_8_OI,
    { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE + IMMED_32 },// ADD_32_OI,
    { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE },// PUSH_ES,
    { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE },// POP_ES,
    { ... }// OR_EB_GB
};

// to access by symbol:
DescriptorByte someOpcode = opcodeList[ADD_GV_EV];
// to access by symbol + offset:
DescriptorByte anotherOpcode = opcodeList[ADD_GV_EV + 5];
```

Note about performance. At the machine code level, a struct and a statically sized array will perform exactly the same. They are ptr+offset fields. This is exactly what `std::array` will compile into. `std::vector` will have more overhead because it supports varying sizes, so only use it if you will have `OpcodeList` objects that have different sizes.

Regarding initialization, it's true this is more verbose / uglier than what you have, but it's a worthy effort to keep things manageable.

Comment: I am worried about performance, there is room for more than 510 opcodes on intel x86 and x64, so i was hoping i could use some pointer and a displacement for it.

Comment: how about adding into the vector the members like:

DescriptorByte ADD_8_OI =   { TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, OPBASE + IMMED_8 };
etc

Do i need to use vector.assing for each one in the list? :/

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this using your `struct`:

```
OpcodeList opcodelist;
BYTE count = 5;
void* p1 = &opcodelist;
DescriptorByte* p2 = (DescriptorByte*)p1;
DescriptorByte = *(p2 + count);
```